# How can I develop with multiple person on bot framework composer?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

I want to develop with Bot Framework Composer with a few programmers (V2.1.2)

As far as I know, the collaborative workspace exists on the power virtual agents side, but we want to work on bot framework composer because of serious license fees. How can we work on a collaborative bot on Bot Framework Composer, synchronously or asynchronously?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Commit the bot composer bot folder to a Git repository and share the config/settings among your team mates so they can run it locally.